# Javascript descramble BitCoin miner

Tags: javascript, decode, data-mining, obfuscation, bitcoin

I noticed that some web pages include javascript code for bitcoin mining. The code looks scrambled like this :

```
new Function(atob("dmFyIF8weDg5ZDkgPSBbCiAgImdldEFjY2VwdGVkSGFzaGVzIiwKICAiZ2V0VG9
```

So my questions are :

1) how JavaScript code is encoded this way and still being understood by the browser ?

2) Is there anyway to de-scramble the code ?

Comment: The word is _obfuscated_ and it is perfectly understandable by the browser. You need to de-obfuscate it or run it in a sandbox